No/Low-Code Web-based Form for Adding Data to a SQLite DB?
I have seen some variations on this question in the archives, but nothing that exactly fits my situation, especially from recent times.
I have a SQLite database. Two teammates and I will be adding data to it over the next six months. I would like to create a web-based form that we can all use that would be capable of updating multiple tables at once from a single form.
Considerations:

This is a non-commercial, time-limited academic research project; I'm looking for something free or low-cost if at all possible.
I will need to be able to export my DB at the end of data entry, in either SQLite or Postgres format, OR, worst case, in a series of CSVs that I can wire up a DB from afterward.

Does a no/low code solution for this use exist? I've been examining the free tiers of some possibilities: ReTool is a maybe -- I think I could use the free tier for data entry, but not sure if it will allow me to export my Postgres DB afterward, and I don't know reliable it is. NoCoDB is a no -- it allows you to build forms, but only to update one table at a time; you can't use a form to update multiple tables across a base. I've seen PHPDatabaseForm, but it's a bit beyond my technical capabilities, especially in the time I currently have.
Any other suggestions? I'd be grateful for any input.

Here a brief list:

FileMaker: it was free. Then it became licensed. Now they are going free again.
Microsoft Access: old but still makes the job
Airtable: This is the most popular free alternative to Claris FileMaker. It combines the functionality of a spreadsheet with the capabilities of a database
NocoDB: An open-source platform that turns any database into a smart spreadsheet
LibreOffice Base: This is a free, open-source database management tool that offers features similar to Microsoft Access

And now a few questions:

"Two teammates and I will be adding data to it over the next six months": How much data? A lot of data? In bulk import?
"capable of updating multiple tables at once from a single form." are you trying to import CSV?


Info: must is be browser based?
You won't accept a desktop app?   Like SqliteBrowser
See also https://superuser.com/questions/461154/easy-and-simple-sqlite-database-gui
And https://turso.tech/blog/5-best-free-sqlite-gui mentions

SQLite Viewer
If you're looking for something that runs in the browser, and has a familiar UI feeling, then SQLite Viewer is a great choice. It's a free, open-source, and cross-platform SQLite database browser that runs in the browser.
SQLite Viewer also boasts a number of features that make it easy to find what you're looking for with full text search, and the ability to filter and sort your data.


There are dozens of standalone apps, although my favo(u)rite is HeidiSQL
